# How to change textframe creation order in Indesign

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am writing a script for Indesign. In that script I am taking the contents of the textframes and save them to a database. Till here my script works. However when looping between textframes script uses creation order. I want to save to database in question order.

Here is my script:

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;var frameList = myDocument.textFrames;
for (var i = 0; i < frameList.length; i++){ 
    var txt=frameList[i].contents;
    SaveToDB(txt);
}
```

So is there a way to change creation order of textframes

[image: Indesign I'm working with]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to change the "creation order", you simply need to rearrange the text frames in the Layers panel. The text frame at the lowest position in the stack will be treated as if it were created first, and the one at the highest position as if it were created last.

However, I know of no way to change this stack order via script (if somebody knows one, I would be curious to hear it).

So your choices are to either manually rearranging this stack order in the Layers panel and then run your script or to sort it by the question numbers (as Jongware suggested over at StackExchange GraphicDesign).

Comment: You can get index of your textFrame and use bringForward() or sendBackward() to change the stuck positioning on the layer. Also you can just position the frames on different layers - this has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is - it does not look like it is possible. Text frames are added to textFrames in the order they are created and there are no methods to move them around. The textFrame object has index property, but it is read only.

You can create your text frames in the questions order.

The alternative is to sort your array before saving to the database. I think, you would need to use multidimensional array and generate your sort order there. You can try to grab a few first characters from your text frame as it seems to represent the question number. Another way is to add script labels as your sort order.

Finally, let database to sort them. The order you store the records in the database is usually not that important as the database queries add sorting anyway